# cookies in angular $http post requests

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I'm connecting to some non documented apis using angular `$http` requests in a ionic app.

I have two different apis I use and both of them use `Set-Cookie`, one of them works fine without me having to pick certain cookies for the calls or even use cookie headers in the `$http` posts.

But not in the other one, that gives me multiple `Set-Cookies` and only use some of them for the next calls, is there some way I can see what cookies that are sent in my `$http` post or see what cookies that are stored or something like that?

my guess is I'm not sending the right one's, the only difference from my `rest-client` "where it works" is that in angular I don't know what cookies I'm sending..

**EDIT**

Here is the response I'm getting which include the coookies I need for another call

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: text/plain
date: Wed, 23 Sep 2015 20:39:38 GMT
cache-control: private
sebstatus: 200
expires: Wed, 23 Sep 2015 20:38:38 GMT
sebstatusmessage: OK: status=Success errorCode= errorMessage=
Set-Cookie: WM7NET=4bap4pcjijvoqgpi153daxmv;Secure; Path=/
Set-Cookie: WM7NET=4bap4pcjijvoqgpi153daxmv; Path=/
Set-Cookie: WM7=osTkv3IzxAlK5WApfphBw1Tko3OVS0;Secure; Path=/
Set-Cookie: iampsc1110=rd520o00000000000000000000ffff0a101fa2o1110;secure; path=/
Set-Cookie: TSaee27a=884dc16339c369b257519e459c177d77a0094933039a35c356030e0a3b92707026ec4c7f3b92707026ec4c7fed2d4e69f9e16a0af3fdf509a27e412a; Path=/
Set-Cookie:    avr_1380360832_0_0_4294901760_2725612627_2=1875832750_21493071;max-      age=300;path=/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: Keep-alive
```

and here is the call I'm doing to the next step.

```
    var data = {'SB_Referer': '/priv/ServiceFactory-mbid'}


    $http({
        withCredentials: true,
        url: 'https://mp.example.se/nauth2/Authentication/Auth?SB_Referer=/priv/ServiceFactory-mbid',
        method: 'POST',
        transformRequest: function(obj) {
            var str = [];
            for(var p in obj)
            str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
            // console.log('string is', str)
            return str.join("&");
        },
        data: data,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
            'User-Agent': 'SB-Prkund/6.1.3 CFNetwork/672.1.14 Darwin/14.0.0',
            'Proxy-Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Accept-Language': 'sv-se',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
            'Content-Length': 0,
        }
    }).then(function(response){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data), response.status, response.headers('Set-Cookie'), response.config)
    })
```

Comment: So, a) you havent given us any information about the apis, whos? b) there is no code we can check...

Comment: have you tried using `withCredentials` header? Really not much info to work from here

Comment: I have added some more details

Comment: @charlietfl is there anything obvious missing in what i do?

Comment: read up on what `withCredentials` does.

Comment: @charlietfl the point is im sending the request from an app on a device so cors is no problem and i do the exact same thing without the withcredentials on the other api and it works fine, what i need to do is how to handle the cookies

Comment: but `withCredentials` is cookie related

Comment: @charlietfl so if i get 2 cookies on first post and two more on second post and for the third i need one from first and one from second i can use withCredentials?

Comment: @charlietfl is there an answer to this, because I'm not finding it.

Comment: not entirely clear what you need to be honest

Comment: @charlietfl okay, like this I need to be able to pick cookies and use them for my call, so if I for example needed the first three Set-Cookie values for my call and leave the rest how would I get them and send those in a Cookie header

Comment: fine...but in browser there are some cookies you can't access with script. I don't know about your environment. You will need to see if you have access to those cookies directly or not. In corss domain situations using the header i mentioned takes care of including necessary cookies

Comment: @charlietfl yes and in that case how do I get access to them?

Comment: will have to research that yourself. My guess is somethings wrong in the approach if `withCredentials` doesn't work. Or there are api criteria you aren't managing correctly